# how to use variable inside .wrap()

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might sound silly but i'm having trouble printing a variable in this code -

```
var clsuffix = "something";
$("#box").wrap('<div class="boxy" />');
```

I want to print the **clsuffix** variable inside the class=" *here* "
so it could be like

```
<div class="boxysomething">
```

But when i use the variable inside class="", it comes up as it is (not being treated as variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate it in.  Ultimately, your goal is to build a string consisting of the literal `"boxy"` and the contents of the variable `clsuffix`.  That is done with `"boxy" + clsuffix` in JavaScript:

```
$("#box").wrap('<div class="boxy' + clsuffix + '" />');
```

If you were just trying to insert the variable into the string (such as you might do in a PHP double-quoted string), it won't be interpreted by JavaScript:

```
// Doesn't work in JavaScript:
$("#box").wrap('<div class="boxyclsuffix" />');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#box').wrap('<div />', {'class' : 'boxy' + cslsuffix});
```

Which effectively creates the `div` element, and uses the map to assign values to the defined attributes.